# Using Solver add-in with on cells that use the rand() function

Tags: vba, excel, random, solver

I have a monte carlo simulation model and I need to set one of my parameters (service level) to be at least 95%. The problem is that, from what I know, when Solver runs, it tries different solutions, but because of RAND() function, the target cells keeps on changing all the time. Is there any way I could deal with this? Disable RAND() from changing temporarly? I tried to switch calculations to manual but that doesnt work because then the target cell does not update at all. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Just use the VBA `Rnd()` function to put random values where you need them when you need them. Call `Randomize` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do is to create your own `=RAND()` function (let's call it `MYRAND()` function) that takes an `ON/OFF` input. The idea is:

1. You open the VBE Editor and add a module to your workbook;
2. You insert your "Random on/off function", something like this:

   ```
   Public Function MYRAND(ByVal activation As String) As Double
   Application.Volatile
   If activation = "ON" Then
       MYRAND = Rnd()
   Else
       MYRAND = Application.Caller.Value
   End If
   End Function
   ```

Now, you can put a listbox containing "ON/OFF" into a cell (let's say A1) and reference it into the cell like `=MYRAND(A1)`. From now, if the value of A1 is at `ON`, the function will return the classic result you would expect from the `=RAND()` function. However, if it's at `OFF`, in that case it will just skip the calculation and let the previous value inside.

Like this you would be simulating the effect of `Calculation Manual/Automatic` but applying it to the `RAND()` function only, leaving all the rest independent.

Comment: Just a note: `Application.Volatile`, once run, tells the `Application` instance to re-calculate the function everytime the worksheet is changed (i.e. the same recalculation occurring when using the `RAND()`)

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks for the answer, it works! I just get a message "Circular references" every time I change the listbox to "OFF". But after I press OK, it behaves perfectly, like it should. Is there a way of getting rid of this "circular references" message? If not, no worries, this helps so much already!

Comment: Yes, actually what happens is you create a circular reference every time it's "OFF", because you ask the function to be equal to its same cell's value. However, once you click on "OK", you're authorizing Excel to create the circular reference at your "risk" and that's why you see the message only the first time. In this case, there's no risk but you have to accept the reference the first time. I'm not at the computer now, but try to follow the "Help" to see how to get rid of the message (or just temporarily deactivate the alerts of the Application object).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [original authors](https://www.utexas.edu/courses/lasdon/design3.htm) of the solver, it is designed to use Excel's built-in logic for determining what needs to be recalculated.  This means that at each step, the solver will tweak a value, and then ask Excel to recalculate.  At that point in time, the `Rand` functions will run, since they are volatile.

What I would recommend is to take your randomly generated numbers and hard code them into your sheet (paste special -> values), then run the solver, and then put your calls to `Rand` back in, once your model is calibrated.